# Shapeless Example on computing deltas type mismatch error

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to replicate the example from the Shapeless-Easy talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKaCCYZYBWo). The code for it can be found here: https://harrylaou.com/scala/shapeless/deltas/

Alternatively please see below for

```
sealed trait Diff[A]

final case class Identical[A](value: A) extends Diff[A]

final case class Different[A](left: A, right: A) extends Diff[A]

object Diff {
  def apply[A](left: A, right: A): Diff[A] =
    if (left == right) Identical(left)
            else       Different(left, right)
}
```

```
trait SimpleDelta[R <: HList] extends DepFn2[R, R] {
  type Out <: HList //Result is bounded by HList
}

object SimpleDelta {

/** type alias Aux adds as a type parameter the return Type. 
  * It is convenient in order to constrain it 
  * by passing it as a type parameter.
  */
  type Aux[I <: HList, O <: HList] = SimpleDelta[I]{ type Out = O }

  //Recursive Algorithm
  implicit def hnilDelta: Aux[HNil, HNil] = new SimpleDelta[HNil] {

    type Out = HNil

    def apply(l: HNil, r: HNil): Out = HNil
  }

  implicit def hconsDelta[H, T <: HList, DT <: HList]
    (implicit tailDelta: Aux[T, DT]) : Aux[H::T, Diff[H] :: DT] =
        new SimpleDelta[H :: T]{
            type Out = Diff[H] :: DT

            def apply(l: H :: T, r: H :: T) : Out =
                Diff(l.head, r.head) :: tailDelta(l.tail, r.tail)
        }

  def apply[A, R <: HList](l: A, r: A)
    (implicit genA: Generic.Aux[A, R],
              delta: SimpleDelta[R]): delta.Out = 
                    delta(genA.to(l), genA.to(r))
}
```

On this line here

```
def apply(l: H :: T, r: H :: T) : Out =
        Diff(l.head, r.head) :: tailDelta(l.tail, r.tail)
```

I receive the error "type mismatch". Where the Required type is "Out" and Found type is Diff[H]::DT.

The type that is specified directly above this line is that `type Out = Diff[H] :: DT`. Not sure why this doesn't work

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your code compiles without errors https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Hl3oVFMJQ82KhBNOvm7m6A What's your Scala version?

Comment: scala version is 2.12.8

Comment: Well, in 2.12.8 it compiles as well. Do `sbt clean compile`.